# Navigation2d use with move_and_slide in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

Rewritten and Edited for clarity. Assume that I have a 2d platformer like the following example:

https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/blob/master/2d/kinematic_character/player.gd

Now... Say I have the player location (vector2) and the enemy location (vector2). The enemy movement works just like the player in the above example. I use get_simple_path to build an array of pre-existing points that lead from the enemy location to the player location. How do I use that array with move_and_slide to get the enemy from point A to point B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
const GRAVITY = 1000
const SLOPE_SLIDE_STOP = false

var speed = 250
var velocity = Vector2()

var points = [Vector2(100, 200), Vector2(200, 400), Vector2(400, 800)]
var current_point = null

func _physics_process(delta):
    if points and current_point is null:
        current_point = points.pop_front()

    if current_point:
        if current_point.distance_to(position) > 0:
            target_direction = (position - current_point).normalized()

            velocity.y += delta * GRAVITY

            velocity = lerp(velocity, target_speed, 0.1)
            velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, target_direction, SLOPE_SLIDE_STOP)
        else:
            current_point = null
```

Comment: Clever, that's basically what I'm doing now to detect which side the player is on in relation to the enemy. I was more looking for a method of looping through an array of Vector2 points, but I just realized I should be able to figure that out on my own. I'll award you the correct answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! I updated the answer so it works with a list of Vector2 points. Hope it helps.